# Halloween Trick or Treat how many in each neighborhood?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

my son was trick or treating this halloween and met with family and friends after hitting about 3 neighborhoods which had the same amount of candy . placing his spoils in 3 bags for each neighborhood  , when he split up the 1rst bag between 3 of us he had 2 pieces left over . when he split the 2nd bag up 5 ways to his friends he had 3 pieces left over . Lastly he split the 3rd bag up between 7 friends who came over after they found out how much candy he had collected, leaving 2 pieces left over . How much candy was in each neighborhood ? prove your answer

Comment: The answer is $23$. Now you should prove it for yourself.

Comment: Proving it would be easier : \begin{align} 23 mod 3 &= 1\\ 23 mod 5 &= 3\\ 23 mod 7 &= 2\\ \end{align}

Comment: i cant write in that damn math jax  i have it written down here in my notenbuch ..i dont think i can send pic here can i ?

Comment: its using chinese remainder theorem

Comment: @Randin you can edit your question and attach the picture of the notes.

Comment: i will soon ..ru sure it will be allowed ?

Comment: and how to i post pic from android device ?

Comment: its actually the same sun tsu problem from his book over thousands of years ago that virtually proves ancient aliens had messed with the chinese peoples genetics circa 3000 b.c. ( also proves the ancient chinese had discovered what we now call chinese remainder theorem . )